# Python doctest: result with multiple lines

Tags: python, multiline, doctest

I can't get a `doctest` to work with a result which contains multiple lines and may contain empty lines at the beginning. This is probably caused by indentation and parsing issues. I've figured out some solutions:

- Write the desired result to a file, and `doctest` the comparison between the result and the file contents.
- Compare a hash of the result to a known hash. The main disadvantage of this approach is that the reader of the `doctest` learns very little about the desired result.
- Find a way to make doctest work with multi line results.
- Use `unittest` instead of `doctest`.

Any ideas?

### Code:

```
    >>> data_lists=[ {"Average execution" : [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]},
    ...                              {"Top execution"     : [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 6]},
    ...                              {"Current execution" : [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5]}       ]
    >>> c=Chart(data_lists,
    ...         ("Large<br>rooster", "Rsync rooster", "Pool<br>Chicken", "Disease"),
    ...         width=700, height=300)
    >>> print c.html.strip()
    <div id="placeholder3" style="width:700px;height:300px"></div>

    <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

    var d0 = [[0, 1], [4, 2], [8, 3], [12, 2], [16, 3]];
    var d1 = [[1, 3], [5, 4], [9, 5], [13, 7], [17, 8], [21, 11], [25, 6]];
    var d2 = [[2, 1], [6, 2], [10, 1], [14, 2], [18, 1], [22, 5]];

        $.plot($("#placeholder3"), [

        {   label: "Average execution",  data: d0,   bars: { show: true }  },
        {   label: "Top execution",  data: d1,   bars: { show: true }  },
        {   label: "Current execution",  data: d2,   bars: { show: true }  }

        ],
        {
            xaxis: { ticks: [[1.5, "Large<br>rooster"], [5.5, "Rsync<br>rooster"], [9.5, "Pool<br>Chicken"], [13.5, "Disease"]] }
        }
        );
    });
    </script>
```

### Error:

```
**********************************************************************
File "HTML.py", line 28, in __main__.Chart.__init__
Failed example:
    print c.html.strip()
Expected:
    <div id="placeholder3" style="width:700px;height:300px"></div>
Got:
    <div id="placeholder3" style="width:700px;height:300px"></div>
    <BLANKLINE>
        <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
    <BLANKLINE>
        var d0 = [[0, 1], [4, 2], [8, 3], [12, 2], [16, 3]];
        var d1 = [[1, 3], [5, 4], [9, 5], [13, 7], [17, 8], [21, 11], [25, 6]];
        var d2 = [[2, 1], [6, 2], [10, 1], [14, 2], [18, 1], [22, 5]];
    <BLANKLINE>
            $.plot($("#placeholder3"), [
    <BLANKLINE>
            {   label: "Average execution",  data: d0,   bars: { show: true }  },
            {   label: "Top execution",  data: d1,   bars: { show: true }  },
            {   label: "Current execution",  data: d2,   bars: { show: true }  }
    <BLANKLINE>
            ],
            {
                xaxis: { ticks: [[1.5, "Large<br>rooster"], [5.5, "Rsync rooster"], [9.5, "Pool<br>Chicken"], [13.5, "Disease"]] }
            }
            );
        });
        </script>
**********************************************************************
1 items had failures:
   1 of   3 in __main__.Chart.

__init__
***Test Failed*** 1 failures.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put `<BLANKLINE>` in the expected output just like it shows in the error message. Then the test should work just fine. The expected input terminates at the first whitespace only line which is why you have to mark it specially:

```
>>> data_lists=[ {"Average execution" : [1, 2, 3, 2, 3]},
...                              {"Top execution"     : [3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 11, 6]},
...                              {"Current execution" : [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 5]}       ]
>>> c=Chart(data_lists,
...         ("Large<br>rooster", "Rsync rooster", "Pool<br>Chicken", "Disease"),
...         width=700, height=300)
>>> print c.html.strip()
<div id="placeholder3" style="width:700px;height:300px"></div>
<BLANKLINE>
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
<BLANKLINE>
var d0 = [[0, 1], [4, 2], [8, 3], [12, 2], [16, 3]];
var d1 = [[1, 3], [5, 4], [9, 5], [13, 7], [17, 8], [21, 11], [25, 6]];
var d2 = [[2, 1], [6, 2], [10, 1], [14, 2], [18, 1], [22, 5]];
<BLANKLINE>
    $.plot($("#placeholder3"), [
<BLANKLINE>
    {   label: "Average execution",  data: d0,   bars: { show: true }  },
    {   label: "Top execution",  data: d1,   bars: { show: true }  },
    {   label: "Current execution",  data: d2,   bars: { show: true }  }
<BLANKLINE>
    ],
    {
        xaxis: { ticks: [[1.5, "Large<br>rooster"], [5.5, "Rsync<br>rooster"], [9.5, "Pool<br>Chicken"], [13.5, "Disease"]] }
    }
    );
});
</script>
```

See the doctest documentation which explains this: http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#how-are-docstring-examples-recognized

Comment: +1 ACC works, but still many errors caused by indentation mismatches. Perhaps doctest isn't the best tool for the job.

Answer (score 3):

Use `<BLANKLINE>` for indicating blank lines in output, just like the failure output says `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Besides using `<BLANKLINE>` as suggested in the other answers, this option can be useful:

```
>>> print c.html.strip()  # doctest: +NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE
```

Especially if the expected output contains `\r` (carriage return) characters, in which case `<BLANKLINE>` won't match without `NORMALIZE_WHITESPACE` set.